# How to save the result of a formula in a string instead of the formula itself

Tags: vba, string, formula

`Dim strSetup As String`
`strSetupOpm = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-1],data!R2C1:R20C2,2,FALSE),""no data"")"`
`cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = strSetup`

This is working but the string passes the formula , not the result of the formula.
How can i change this so i have the result in the string ?

Comment: `cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = cell.Offset(1, 1).Value`?

Comment: you can use `Worksheet.Evaluate` but that would require `A1` not `R1C1` referencing.